# How to depend by parent class

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a class `Handler`. In the constructor I have a `Manager` class which depends on different settings.

```
kernel.Bind<IHandler>().To<Handler>().
                WithConstructorArgument("manager", 
                new Manager(kernel.Get<IDataAccessFactory>().CreateUnitOfWork(), new Custom1Settings()));
```

How do i create an injection for `Custom1Settings` in `Manager` and which in `Handler`

```
 class Handler
{
    Handler(IManager manager....)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class Manager
{
    Manager(IUnitOfWork unit, ISettings settings)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kernel.Bind<IManager>().To<Manager>().Named("Registration").WithConstructorArgument("settings", new Custom1Settings());

kernel.Bind<IHandler>().To<Handler>().WithConstructorArgument("manager", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IManager>("Registration"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ninject` automatically figures out dependencies. It's one of it's most useful features.

Define a binding for `Custom1Settings` and `Manager` and it will automatically inject it.

So

```
kernel.Bind<IManager>().To<Manager>();
kernel.Bind<ICustom1Settings>().To<Custom1Settings>();
```

Comment: I have two implementation of ICustom1Settings

Comment: Okay, which do you want to use?